# Is XMLInputFactory thread-safe?

Tags: java, xml, java-7, stax

When profiling my application, I noticed that creating instances of XMLInputFactory over and over is very expensive. Is it safe to share its instances across multiple threads?

The javadoc doesn't say anything about its thread-safety and searching the internet doesn't give a definite answer!

Comment: Yes, it is thread safe.

Comment: @jakub.petr Can you point me to some documentation or resource which discusses this?

Comment: maybe it's not https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIOM-74

Comment: I peeked into OpenJDK sources and just configuration must be synchronized. But I must say, that it may depend upon implementation. XMLInputFactory itself is abstract!

Comment: true. @Chandru what JDK are you using?

Comment: not sure about jdk7, but check this out http://svn.codehaus.org/woodstox/wstx/trunk/release-notes/USAGE - it seems to be for woodstox

Comment: @Leo Looks like I added my answer at the same time as your comment. Provide it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Hi, does anyone has an answer on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have decided to use [Woodstox](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/) as the StAX implementation. It is both much faster than the default JDK implementation and [explicitly mentions thread safety](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/Performance).

> Woodstox factories are thread-safe after configuration phase (calling setProperty()), but not during it. Most importantly, once all configuration is done, calling 'createXMLxxx' methods is fully thread-safe.